# New maths puzzle

Tags: logical-deduction, computer-puzzle

The objective is to blacken certain boxes. The numbers outside represent the sum of the numbers contained in the white boxes in the corresponding rows or columns.

[image]

Comment: Does a row not having a number mean it can sum to whatever we want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the unique solution, obtained via integer linear programming:

> [image]

I used SAS:

```
proc optmodel;
   set ROWS = 1..12;
   set COLS = ROWS;
   num a {ROWS, COLS} = [
      18 14 18 18  4 17  5 14  6  4 17 11
      13 10  8 10  4 17 17  6  8  6  2 16
       5  8 18 17 14  3 18  4 14 10 15 18
       6 16 16 11  2 15 16  3 10  5  3 17
       5 15 12  1  2  2  4 13 14 15 13 16
      18  3 16 10  8  1 10  8 14  5  7 12
      16  5 10  1  6 10  4  9  1 16 15 10
      12  8 16 14  1 18  6 14  3  4 16 17
       7  5  9 13  9 13 12 17  2 14 18 14
       5  3 15  3 11 18 15 10  9 10  5  6
      13  4  4  5  5 14  1 13 13 18 12  1
       8 10 13  1 10 17 15 11  6  7  3 12
   ];
   num rowSum {ROWS} = [
      56  . 61 50 10 62  . 78 76 80 24 66
   ];
   num colSum {COLS} = [
      54 21 40 59 29 80 78 97 55 62 62 51
   ];

   var X {ROWS, COLS} binary;
   con RowSumCon {i in ROWS: rowSum[i] ne .}:
      sum {j in COLS} a[i,j] * X[i,j] = rowSum[i];
   con ColSumCon {j in COLS: colSum[j] ne .}:
      sum {i in ROWS} a[i,j] * X[i,j] = colSum[j];

   solve noobj;

   create data soldata from [i j] X a/format=2.;
quit;

proc sgplot data=soldata aspect=1 noautolegend noborder;
   heatmapparm x=j y=i colorresponse=X / colormodel=(black white) outline;
   text x=j y=i text=a;
   xaxis display=none;
   yaxis display=none reverse;
run;
```

Comment: do you do your linear programming with Python? I seem to remember that. Do you have a googlable resource for your methods?

Comment: @DrXorile No, I use the OPTMODEL procedure in SAS: https://go.documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/v_041/casmopt/casmopt_optmodel_toc.htm You can google my name and SAS OPTMODEL